# Parsing Excel files with Python 3.x

Tags: excel, parsing, python-3.x

I have found very few libraries in Python able to parse excel files, and none of them were in Python 3.x nor passed with success the 2to3 step.

What would be your suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Python Package Index (Pypi), section Python 3](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=browse&c=533&show=all) .
xlrd3 is a port of xlrd, a python 2.x lib to parse Excel files.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to contact the authors of the libraries and help port them. It's not horribly hard and quite fun! Your only other option is to use Python 2, and that is obviously not as fun. :)

Possibly you could export to CSV as well, but I guess you would have if that was an option.

Comment: I've begun some work to port the library, but it seems to be quite complicated. Concerning the CSV option, as you guessed I can't ;)

Answer (score 1):

[xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/) is a good tool I've found, and practically the only one for Python 3 that hasn't been discontinued.
I know it works well with both Linux and Windows--LibreOffice in both Linux and Windows, and Excel in Windows.